# How to pass multiple params in org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap as header via POSTMAN or Swagger UI

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman, swagger-ui

I have developed a micro-service consuming MultiValueMap as header parameters, where we are passing authorization string and few other checksums under the same key as "**authorization**".

Everything works perfectly when I am calling this controller via RestTemplate or any rest-client in code, but looking for a solution to pass this MultiValueMap from POSTMAN or even from Swagger UI

Comment: Hey did you find the answer for this ?